# Git: How to list the commits of a patch file

Tags: git, format-patch

I have a patch file (which somebody made with `git format-patch HEAD~3 HEAD --stdout > his_last_3_commits.patch` following more or less [that site](https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/))

I would like to know **how to list the content** (I mean here **the title of the commits**) which are in that `his_last_3_commits.patch` ?

Comment: Does `git apply --summary < his_last_3_commits.patch` work?

Comment: No that command only list all the files affected by the patch, not the commits list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final command I did (thanks to [answer by Gary Fixler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16166548/535203) and [a forum](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/92492-convert-email-headers-encoding.html)) :

```
grep "^Subject:" his_last_3_commits.patch | sed "s/'/\\\\\\\\\\\'/g" | xargs --max-args=1 -I% php -r "echo iconv_mime_decode('%', 0, 'UTF-8');echo \"\n\";"
```

PS : if someone knows a `git` command which does that, don't hesistate to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the commit messages, would this be enough?

```
grep "^Subject:" his_last_3_commits.patch
```

You'll only get the first line of each commit message, but if you're sticking with [a good style](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html) for those, they'll be useful.

Comment: There is nothing more... "gitty"? Because the problem with grep is that I see encoded title like "`Subject: [PATCH 1/3] =?UTF-8?q?Correction=20de=20l'intercepteur=20de=20trans?=`"

Comment: I don't know of anything more gitty, sorry. Can you set LANG=en_US.UTF-8 in your bash session to see if it will output more cleanly? I'm afraid that's the best I can do for now. Patches are just text files, though, so they're very inspectable. You can roll something without too much fuss in your scripting language, until you find a more gitty solution.